# Remove Credit Card option from magento 2 checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, credit-card

I don't want to show credit card option in Magento [2.2.2] checkout. From backend only cash on delivery is enable but still credit card is showing. Even whatever payment method i choose [Standard PayPal, PayPal Express or PayFlo pro] along with PayPal still showing Credit Card.

Can any one give me any idea or solution, why Credit Card showing on checkout when only COD enable.

Comment: May be credit card is enable in store view

Answer (score 0):

Go to Admin > STORES > Configuration > SALES > Payment Methods > Other Payment Methods: > Authorize.net Direct Post > Enabled set as a NO.

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue is credit card showing with paypal

There is already a setting over there in magento

Login admin panel :

go to

`Store->Configuration>Payment Methods>Paypal Configuration`

Over there you will find this setting `Enable PayPal Credit` so just set as **`no`**

Hope This would be helpful info to you

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you are looking for this

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-Products-and-Services/disable-the-pay-with-debit-credit-card-option-in-express/td-p/1482016

> The option is called "PayPal Account Optional" and can be found under https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-website-payments   This will allow you to choose if the "guest payment" option will be available or not during checkout.  Note that a buyer will still have the option to create a PayPal account if they do not have one

Answer (score 0):

If it's not manage from backend so you can remove from file. Simply **$_shouldRende**r define **false** in

> vendor/magento/module-paypal/Block/Bml/Shortcut.php

at line no. **25.**

```
protected $_shouldRender = false;
```

Thanks :)